# Wifi Dongle on Armbian, nl80211 driver doesnt work

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, wpa-supplicant

I have problems to get a wifi-USB-dongle working on a linux (Armbian 22.05.0-trunk  with bleeding edge Linux 5.16.20-rockchip64).

the file /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf looks like:

```
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    scan_ssid=1
    ssid="MYSSID"
    psk=MYPASSPHRASE
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

the file /etc/network/interfaces looks like:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# Network is managed by Network manager
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I restarted "systemctl restart makerbase-wlan0.service"
and checked "systemctl status makerbase-wlan0.service"

```
● makerbase-wlan0.service - Makerbasi mkspi WPA supplicant daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/makerbase-wlan0.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-06-17 04:45:44 CST; 22s ago
 Main PID: 5379 (wpa_supplicant)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 998)
   Memory: 940.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/makerbase-wlan0.service
           └─5379 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0

Jun 17 04:45:44 mkspi systemd[1]: Started Makerbasi mkspi WPA supplicant daemon.
Jun 17 04:45:45 mkspi wpa_supplicant[5379]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Jun 17 04:45:45 mkspi wpa_supplicant[5379]: nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
Jun 17 04:45:45 mkspi wpa_supplicant[5379]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jun 17 04:45:45 mkspi wpa_supplicant[5379]: rfkill: Cannot get wiphy information
Jun 17 04:45:45 mkspi wpa_supplicant[5379]: ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
Jun 17 04:45:45 mkspi wpa_supplicant[5379]: ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

I tried several commands (to use another driver) in the /etc/network/interfaces such as:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-driver wext
        wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Nothing has worked so far, for long - There sometimes is a wifi connection (can see it in the router and can even access the WebTerminal), but the next reboot kills the connection again. In the case it worked, I think I needed to unplug the wired connection an than it switches to the wifi. Maybe this is why I tried following command in the commandline, but its effect is not persistent.

```
wpa_supplicant -D wext -iwlan0
```

The linux runs on a 3D Printer, and I'm a little afraid to kill the wired connection somehow (cannot reinstall the system). I'm not experienced with linux so I better ask. Thanks for any advice

Comment: I try to make it more short: How can I enforce wpa_supplicant to use wext instead of nl80211. Feels like this is the call of wpa_supplicant "/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0"  which uses nl80211 first, exit with error, but never try to use wext. Am I wrong? How can I change that call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't solve the issue by software, I changed the hardware and tested several USB wifi dongles to work around this driver nightmare.

Finally an Edimax dongle worked perfectly: lsusb -->

**Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]**

Did not work:

1. Asus USB-N10 Nano B1 (HW Ver.: V1)
2. TPlink TL-WN725N(EU) Ver.:3.0
3. Logilink WL0084B

It's not a "real solution" but maybe the information helps someone someday.